# How to best debug a google analytic events?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm currently integrating support for google analytics in my c++ project. I'm still learning how to use the analytics interface, but I can foresee a few potential issues that I may have with debugging.

I'm currently only able to see the "Event Category" and "Event Action" fields for any events in real time. Is there a way to see "Event Labels" and "Event Values"?

I've only been using the analytics interface for a few hours. How long does it take for events to transfer from Real Time to archived events that can be found in the "Behavior" panel? Currently, I'm not seeing any events in the "Behavior" panel, but there are events in the "Real-Time" panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you click an entry in the event category column in realtime view it will give you a breakdown to action and label for that category.

[Processing latency is documented here:](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)

> Data processing latency Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard
>   accounts that send more than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics
>   will result in the reports being refreshed only once a day. This can
>   delay updates to reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore
>   intra-day processing, reduce the number of sessions your account sends
>   to < 200,000 per day. For Analytics 360 accounts, this limit is
>   extended to 2 billion hits per month.

Most of the time the data will show up a lot quicker (in some of my accounts the data turns up within the hour; anecdotally I'd say it depends to some extent on the account size/number of hits. Also for a Premium/360 account guaranteed processing latency is 4 hours). But if you need  to rely on it for any business criticall purpose you'd better go for the documented number.

For your title question how to "*best*" debug, I'd probably start by installing some kind of proxy that allows to inspect the actual request. This will allow you to better track down the cause of the error, if any.